# ArrayList の操作・参照時にエラー java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 333 out of bounds for length 1

Tags: java

以下のページの要件を元に、Javaでなんちゃって会員登録機能を作成しております。

[作って覚えるプログラミング精選課題集(Java基礎編） - レベル4 会員登録機能](https://qiita.com/s_hino/items/85ce20cb675484d300f0#%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB4-%E4%BC%9A%E5%93%A1%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD)

コードを記述し終わり動かしてみた所、エラーが発生してうまくデータが出力されません。

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 333 out of bounds for length 1
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

記述しているコードには問題はないと思うのですが、直し方がわかりません。
お手数ですがご教授お願い致します。

2/24追記
Register.javaのコードを修正した所、
このようなデータが表示されました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### ソースコード

Register.java

```
package rensyu;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;

public class Register {
    static ArrayList<Kaiin> kaiinAll = new ArrayList<Kaiin>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Register r = new Register();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("何人登録しますか？");
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        int id = 0;
        String name = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.println("会員IDを入力してください");
            id = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("名前を入力してください");
            name = scan.next();
            kaiinAll.add(r.kaiinAdd(id, name));
            Kaiin lastElement = kaiinAll.get(kaiinAll.size() - 1);
            System.out.println(lastElement);
            
        }

    }

    private Kaiin kaiinAdd(int id, String name) {
        Kaiin k = new Kaiin();
        k.setId(id);
        k.setName(name);
        Date d = new Date();
        k.setAddDate(d);
        return k;

    }

}
```

Kaiin.java

```
package rensyu;
import java.util.Date;
public class Kaiin {
    int id;
    String name;
    Date addDate;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getAddDate() {
        return addDate;
    }
    public void setAddDate(Date addDate) {
        this.addDate = addDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`kaiinAll.get(id)` にて、idをキーとして可変長配列から要素を取得しているためです。これはHashMapや連想配列ではないので、挿入した順の配列です。(例えば、スクリーンショットの例外時の本来取得したい項目のインデックスは0です)

たとえば`ArrayList<Kaiin>`から特定のIDを持つ要素を取得したい場合、for-eachループが使えます。

Answer (score 0):

[`ArrayList#add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) は、**リストの最後**に、指定された要素を追加するメソッドです。

ですので、直前に追加した要素を取得するには、[`ArrayList#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) の引数に、**リストの最後**の要素を示す**インデックス**を渡せば良いです。

インデックスは0始まりなので、**リストの最後**の要素を示す**インデックス**は `リストの要素数 - 1` になります。

まとめると、

```java
Kaiin lastElement = kaiinAll.get(kaiinAll.size() - 1);
```

で直前に登録した会員オブジェクトを取得できます。

質問文の実装

```java
kaiinAll.get(id)
```

は、インデックスとは無関係の値を引数にしています。

(コメントを受けて追記)

> 修正しましたが、うまく表示されませんでした。

`System.out.println()` の引数にオブジェクトを渡すと [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) メソッドにより生成された文字列が出力されます。`Kaiin` クラスは `toString()` メソッドを実装していないので、デフォルト実装

```java
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

が用いられます。
これはおそらく期待する出力とは異なるでしょう。

解決策としては、`Kaiin`クラスで `toString()` をオーバライドして適切に実装を行う、ということが考えられます。

```java
public class Kaiin {
    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // ここで出力する文字列を組み立てる
        return "TODO";
    }
}
```

(ただし、今回の課題は必ずしも `toString()` を利用すべし、というものでは無さそうにも見えます。)

---

なお、リンク先の課題は

> 出力はプログラムの最後にまとめて行ってください。

ということなので、最終的には "直前に登録した要素のインデックスは..." というようなことは考えず、リストに登録されている全要素をループで一気に出力する、ということになるかと思います。

Comment: 修正しましたが、うまく表示されませんでした。